# How to call my_function before every time sprintf is called?

Tags: c++, windows

sprintf is an API provided by platform. I want to filter some format when it is used. My idea is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_sprintf(...)
{
    my_filter_function(...);
    return ::sprintf(...);  
}

#define sprintf my_sprintf
```

Then put these code in pch.

But I am still worrying it can't cover all usages, some one is in prebuilt library and not every project has a pch. Do you have any other idea?

Thanks. It's on windows.

Comment: As you can see from the answers/comments already, there are probably very obscure ways to do it but even then you won't cover all cases but instead will open a can of worms. So the question is, what do you actually want to achieve with this? What exactly do you want to filter, and why? Maybe there is a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: theoretically you could write your own version of the CRT dll, which dynamically loads the platform's version and calls GetProcAddress in order to forward all the calls. Then you'd just have to modify your custom sprintf as above. Then link the program against your custom CRT rather than the microsoft one. Then sit back and watch as the program does all kinds of unexpected stuff, probably crashes and leaves you wondering why you bothered.

Comment: Redirect stdout to a custom output FILE

Comment: @Richard Hodges but this again wouldn't solve the problem when a DLL has a statically linked RTL in it (which the OP also appears to want to have covered according to the semi-last sentence).

Comment: The `#define` is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I know it's nearly impossible in a reasonable way. but if someone can give a practical idea, I will be very happy since it's really unpleasing and boring to replace all usages.

Comment: @P.X. Most programmers' editors provide global search and replace.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That won't help with code already compiled into object code.

Comment: @P.X We're all programmers and I think I can speak for all when I say we completely understand and sympathise with your desire to do something cleverer than edit/recompile the library. 
If you can't edit the source code, you could theoretically edit the object file and patch all references to sprintf to your function in another library...
But again, this will take longer than doing it the boring way and will give you surprising results. Anything inside the library (or anywhere else in your program) that uses sprintf to format formatted data, for example, will be affected.

Comment: @IInspectable: It's clear that that the OP has the source code. You scenario is not just uncommon, it's has an astronomical probability against it... Still, why not post an answer with example of hooking (e.g. using Detours)?

Comment: Thank you all. very useful discussion. Now I realize I was on a dangerous way. I should be more cautious. On the other hand, API Hook sounds very interesting that I am not familiar with, I will do more research, maybe it can solve my problem perfectly, however I won't use it in product code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "overwrite" a built-in function. Furthermore, using a macro to replace its name results in your program having undefined behaviour.

So, don't even try to change the behaviour of the standard library. Really, that way *madness* lies.

Just call `my_sprintf` from your own code and let the platform do what it always did.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question. The question is asking for a drop-in replacement, that works with code compiled into library code already. You'd need an API hook. (No, downvote for factual inaccuracy, and not responding to the question that was asked.)

Comment: Just upvoted for factual accuracy. Enjoy the net +8. (No but indeed I think this is the right answer even though it's not what the OP will like to hear.) And @IInspectable, the API hook is a bad idea and won't work with statically linked RTL inside DLLs and such.

Comment: @IInspectable: It _does_ address the question, because the answer is "do not do this".

Comment: It is indeed helpful to know when something is not possible or very unadvisible. There is no good answer covering all the cases the OP appears to want to cover (i.e. in all other libraries as well!), so I think there is a chance that it's the wrong question and there might be other, better solutions to the underlying problem. It is therefore not helpful to keep the OP on the wrong track.

Comment: The problem is that you _can't_ name your function the same as those included in standard libraries, if those libraries are included. The compiler is obliged to give a compiler error if you do. So like it or not, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @CherryDT: In that case one would point out technically possible, yet unadvisable strategies, so that the OP (and future visitors) would know, when they come across something they already tried/were suggested to try. Provide rationale, **why** it is not advisable, and list limitations. In it's current form, this 'answer' simply isn't, and I voted on it to convey as much.

Comment: @Lundin: An implementation is not required to produce any diagnostics for this case of undefined behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable Hmm ok it seems that C and C++ are different here. Not quite sure why C++ is so obsessed with creating undefined behavior everywhere...

Comment: An answer to the question exists, that doesn't exhibit undefined behavior: You can install a hook on the original CRT implementation and perform any operations before calling `sprintf` or after it returns. There is no requirement to use any particular symbol name for the hook function either, and you can use any valid identifier. This answer voices opinions only, based on a partial picture (i.e. the author doesn't know about legal ways to implement the required functionality). Good advice turns bad quickly, if you do not see the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [variadic functions.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg)

Example:

```
int my_sprintf(char *buffer, char *fmt, ...)
{
    int ret;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    /* insert your filter here */
    /* you CAN NOT re-use a va_list variable after being used */
    ret = vsprintf(buffer, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
```

Note: You are **not** allowed to define a function / macro with the same name as a function from the standard library. It's undefined behaviour.

You have to replace all your calls to `sprintf` with your custom `my_sprintf` function.

Comment: Yes the OP would need to but I don't think "how do I implement this function" was the question. It's how to make this function "override" `sprintf` in the stdlib (observe the `#define`, and the question's prose).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Shoot, you are correct. That's `#define` is undefined behaviour. I still think this also answers the question, since the code OP posted is not correct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Still added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **namespace** concept to define functions with the same names

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace myns
{
    int sprintf(...)
    {
        my_filter_function(...);
        return ::vsprintf(...);  
    }
}
```

than call

```
char buffer[256];
myns::sprintf(buffer, "Hello, %s!\n", "World");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't solve the actual problem which is "But I am still worrying it can't **cover all usages, some one is in prebuilt library** and not every project has a pch."

Comment: @CherryDT: In your case the only way is to redefine standard c library. But it is not a good choice.

Comment: Which you can't do for a **prebuilt library**. It's prebuilt, so you can't retroactively change the RTL it's linked against, in case the link is static. (Yes I know you could identify the function based on a signature like FLIRT and then hook the function inside the DLL when loaded but now we are really on the highway to hell.)

Comment: CherryDT: in this case you can do nothing, just give up and call your function.

Comment: And that's my point exactly. (Note that I'm not the OP, I *quoted* them.)